# Long rise time on UART RX line

Tags: uart, esp32, signal-integrity, rise-time

I'm attempting to replace a controller unit (based on an STM32F1) with my own design (based on ESP32), but I'm stuck at the UART RX (seen from the controller side). The rise time of the signal is too high, in some cases the signal never even reaches its peak.

The original controller has a 10k pullup and nothing else connected to the trace. Rise time can be seen below:
[image: original controller board with 10k]

When I recreate this design on the ESP32 with a 10k pullup, some edges don't even go over 2.5V:
[image: 10k pullup]

With a 2.2k resistor it gets much closer to the original board, and without any ringing, but its not quite there yet either:
[image: 2.2k pullup]

Pin on the ESP32 is configured as input, enabling the internal (30k) resistor does not change anything.

The UART traces are admittedly rather long, but not any longer in my design than in the orignal. Only the last 4-5cm is on the board I'm trying to replace, and they are more like 3cm on my design. The UART traces should have 49 ohms characteristic impedance, however no impedance values are defined for the devices I'm attempting to interface with.

What else can I do to lower the rise time?

Edit:

1. Schematic:
   [image: Schematic]
2. Solved. Setting the output strength of a pin on the ESP32, also sets the input strength.
   Waveform of max output strength:
   [image]

Comment: Are these waveforms from a simulation? They do not look real.

Comment: They are very real

Comment: Please show a schematic.

Comment: What is driving the UART? A pullup shouldn't be needed to make the signal work. Are you using one of those FET based bidirectional level shifters?

Comment: @KevinWhite There's not much to it, but I've updated the post with a schematic.

Comment: @WesleyLee A device connected to a backplane, but its an enclosure that I cannot open. I would presume some MCU but I can't for sure as I cannot open it up.

Comment: What scope probe are you using? Is it a x1? They have very high capacitance ~100pF. What length of cable.backplane is involved?

Comment: What is the \$Ioh\$ of the original chip compared to the ESP32?  Seems like the new design isn't able to deal with the capacitance on the line.

Comment: Well, if the transmitter uses open-drain mode there is very little your end can do about it, except to put a strong enough pull-up to have fast enough rising edges. It does raise a question how they are meant to be interfaced though, like, is there a opto-isolator which can be driven by open-drain output.

Comment: @Aaron you led me down the path of source and sink currents. It turns out that on the ESP32, the so called "output strength" also sets the input strength.
I've edited the post with a waveform of the highest output strength. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinWhite Though I seem to have solved the issue, the waveform was made with the Saleae logic 8

Comment: There is no such thing as pin having an input strength. So setting the output strength of a pin may look like it solved your issue with an input pin, but in reality it is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Add some high ohm pullup resistors and see what happens, uart is open drain in some chips, causing such behavior if the pull-up is too weak.

Careful not to exceed ratings of uart-tx pin.

Comment: I tried with just the internal pullup of the ESP, which seems to be 30k ohm, I suppose that's considered a high ohm pullup. I haven't saved a waveform of that but it resulted in framing errors

Comment: @Cyborgium Then you may be dealing with an damaged pin. Could be ESD.